# Groovy unit test fails mysteriously

Tags: groovy

I am testing some simple XML parsing in Groovy and the following test:

```
assertEquals("TestSuiteParameter1", testSuite.props[0].name)
```

gives a very annoying error:

```
expected:<TestSuiteParameter1> but was:<TestSuiteParameter1>
```

I get the same error if I use the Groovy assert keyword (but with a weirder stacktrace). I bet it's some kind of type mismatch going on but I'm too much of a Groovy n00b to understand what.

Here's what printing their respective classes yield:

```
println testSuite.props[0].name.getClass()
println "TestSuiteParameter1".getClass()
println 'TestSuiteParameter1'.getClass()

class groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
```

Comment: Why not provide the stacktrace?

Comment: The source code for the failing test might prove useful as well...

Comment: The error I provided is the top of the stacktrace and the rest of the testcase was working so I didn't want to clutter up the question. But sure, I probably should have been more clear with that fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`testSuite.props[0].name` is probably a `String` and not a `GString`, while `"TestSuiteParameter1"` on the left side is a `GString` by virtue of double quotes. Change to single quotes and it will probably pass.

This is a common issue in groovy. Confusingly, `"x" != 'x'`.

From the documentation: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString

> GString and String are two distinct classes, and hence use of GString
>   objects as keys for Map objects or comparisons involving GString
>   objects, can produce unexpected results when combined with String
>   objects since a GString and a String won't have the same hashCode nor
>   will they be equal.

Comment: This was more or less the problem, but I had to add a toString() to the end before it worked.

Comment: I wouldn't expect you'd need `toString()` unless `testSuite.props[0].name` wasn't actually a `String` either. But `toString()` will certainly force it to be one.